Round to 1 decimal place and should be double return type
if(cartWeight >= 10)
{
    totalPrice = 100;
    double price = totalPrice - (totalPrice * 18.00 / 100);
    decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:F1}", price));
    price = decimal.ToDouble(val);
    return price;
}

Method Return type shouble be strictly double type and this method should always return 82.0 as double value not decimal.
In the above code val is 82.0 but price is 82 which is not correct, output should be 82.0 after converting decimal to double because the method return type is double.

decimal has an internal flag to remember the number of significant digits. double does not.  While 82 is a value that a double can represent accurately, you have to specify how many significant digits you want when you convert the value to a string. But you don't need to convert from double to string to decimal and back to double.

Dear Sir, I have already specified the significant digits for string in this line
`decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:F1}", price));
i need to return 82.0 as a double return type that's why i am converting string to double.
do you have any code snippet?

#1 - Don't use double to represent a currency value. The value of a double is an approximation, (see is floating point math broken). At some point you will run into rounding errors that you can't solve.
#2 - string.Format is a terrible way to round a value. Use Math.Round.
But to answer your question, there's no difference between 82f and 82.00000f. You get to choose how many digits to display when you convert the value to a string.
While the decimal type does remember the number of significant digits. Meaning that there is a difference between 82m and 82.0000m at least when you convert to a string. double does not waste memory for this purpose.

The value of a double is an approximation To be clear, so is decimal - although it is much better for currency.  But decimal x = 3m * (1m / 3m); Console.WriteLine(x); will NOT display 1; it will display 0.999999999...

(Although decimal is not an approximation for base 10 numbers within a certain range because it uses base 10 numbers, so it does not suffer from approximations for decimal values such as 0.1.)
